# Is it possible to submit a standard HTML form (using jQuery/Ajax) to another standard HTML form on another website?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I would be really grateful for an answer to this question. Is this actually possible?

Let's say website1.com has a very simple form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I then duplicate this on website2.com:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you change the form action on website2.com to point to website1.com, you can easily submit the form data. That's really easy. However, what solutions could you use if you still wanted to submit the data, but not be taken to website1.com on submitting the form? For example you may want to display a custom success page.

I can only think of using jQuery/Ajax, but then you run into the problems of cross-domain security and if you try and circumvent this by using jsonp, you end up getting errors such as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ". I can only guess, because you are submitting data to a standard HTML form and there is nothing at the other end to give a proper response.

How on earth would you do this? I've become a bit stuck. Or is it simply a case that this isn't actually possible unless using a server side scripting language such as PHP?

Comment: You could use AJAX on website2.com to post to a PHP file on website2.com which uses CURL or something to post to website1.com. Unless you open up website1.com to allow AJAX access.

Comment: If you were using PHP you could use the cURL functions to post remotely. The AJAX stuff would take care of your "local" post, but you would not be able to get a status back. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I feel like if I answer this question I could be considered an accomplice...

Comment: You can solve the crossdomain-problem by setting the allow-crossdomain-header on the server

Comment: @JohnnyAW I didn't realise this was even possible. I'll look into that...

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be a solution for you, using action attribute and checking for query string and then use `history.back()`, something like here: http://jsfiddle.net/u262E/  Here is the targeted page: http://jsfiddle.net/w82c3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to an htaccess file on the Apache server:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Ref: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

I could then just do a standard Ajax call without having to worry about jsonp.

Thank you to @JohnnyAW for the suggestion.